# Convert the Brown corpus tagset to upenn tagset

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, corpus

I want to find words in the Brown corpus with a certain upenn tag. I've tried doing this using the following code:

```
poss = ['TO', 'NNS', 'RB', 'DT', 'VBD', 'JJ', 'RBS',
       'PDT', 'IN', 'VBN', 'RP', 'NN', 'VB', 'CC',
       'JJS', 'VBG', 'WRB', 'PRP$', 'WP$', 'WP',
       'EX', 'CD', 'JJR', 'VBZ', 'MD', 'VBP', 'WDT', 'PRP', 'RBR']

PARTS_OF_SPEECH = {p: set() for p in poss}

words = set([(w, t) for w, t in nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_words()])

for word, tag in words:
    if tag in poss:
         PARTS_OF_SPEECH[tag].add(word)
```

so I can do `PARTS_OF_SPEECH["NN"]` to get all the words in Brown with the upenn tag "NN".

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, because `brown.tagged_words()` returns words tagged with Brown tags rather than upenn tags, which are slightly different. I know that there is a `tagset` keyword argument to `brown.tagged_words()`, but I can't find any arguments it takes other than "universal", which isn't what I want. Is there some argument that returns upenn tags?

Comment: You probably have to create a mapping from Brown to upenn tags, or possibly find an existing one. This won't be perfect, though, since tagsets are not easily exchanged. Each tagset is based on separate annotation guidelines, inevitably including differences in the underlying linguistic theory.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this doesn't seem to be possible (see [this](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/483) issue). Workarounds using third-party tools such as [this](https://gist.github.com/nschneid/6476715) might work.